# Why does terminal say it's installing a package that's already installed, when I try to install something completely different?

Tags: command-line, fedora, mate-desktop

I'm on Fedora 23 MATE.

I tried to install virtual box an hour ago but it wouldn't because their website is down.

I had also installed gyazo. That had no issues.

Now when I try to install anything via terminal, it always lists gyazo and VirtualBox as being installed too, even though gyazo is already installed and VirtualBox can't be installed right now.

How come?

Here's a brand new fresh terminal session. I rebooted my machine and I did `sudo dnf clean all` and I rebooted again.

```
[family@hostname LinuxPC ~]$ sudo yum install samba samba-common 
samba-client cups-lib system-config-samba
Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting 
to '/usr/bin/dnf install samba samba-common samba-client cups-lib 
system-config-samba'. See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'
gyazo_gyazo-for-linux-source                      570  B/s | 296  B     00:00
Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for 
https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc
[TCP connection reset by peer]
```

Why does it say it's installing gyazo and VirtualBox when I'm just trying to install samba?

I tried to open yum extender to clear those packages but I can't open it. It always crashes because of some Python error. So I can’t fix it that way.

Comment: Is virtualbox.org one of your repos? dnf may just be trying to update its package lists.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities: either you get those included because, like now, previous efforts in getting those packages have failed, and `dnf` is retrying.

Or because `yum` and `dnf` keep different additional data about packages, and you seem to be insisting on using deprecated software, you managed to install `gyazo` using plain `yum` and you got `dnf` confused.

So transfer the transaction metadata from `yum` to `dnf`, and if that doesn't help, deinstall and reinstall `gyazo` **by using** `dnf`